# String Date To convert DateTime using ParseExact

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a string and it comes as a `DD/MM/YYYY` style.(eg : 11/07/2018)

I need to convert this To `DateTime` format and `YYYY-MM-DD` style.

I tried it using `DateTime.Parse` but can't

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate))
{
   frm = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
else if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
{
   todt = DateTime.ParseExact(toDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

Comment: ParseExact() the string with dd/MM/yyyy then call ToString() on the resulting  DateTime to get your desired format (which will be a string of course).

Comment: @AlexK. Finally i need DateTime Format

Comment: Side note: it seems, you don't want `else if` but two separated `if`

Comment: A DateTime variable has no format, format only applies when you look at it as a string, so if you want a specific format you really want a string.

Comment: As Alex said, DateTime has no human-readable formatting. The only time value stored is `Ticks`, everything else is calculated from `Ticks`.

Comment: Why everybody answer in comment an not post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one line of code.

```
var newDateString = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Keep in mind that a `DateTime` instance is a data structure that does not have a format. When dealing with dates and times it is best to only revert to a human readable string when you need to present/output the value for a human to read. For anything else including persistence to a storage system that supports types (like a relational database) leave the value as a `DateTime` type.

Example: If you wanted `yyyy-MM-dd` because you wanted to persist this to Sql Server then you should stop after the parsing (and not call ToString). You can then assign the `DateTime` instance to a command parameter's `Value` property directly.

Answer (score 1):

Convert using `ParseExact` and then use `ToString` to the target format:

```
    string dateS = "30/04/2018";
    DateTime dateD = DateTime.ParseExact(dateS, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string dateS2 = dateD.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Here is a working example in fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0yuZ6